# backbone.js click event not firing when new DOM element is added by view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have written a simple program to create form post. When a new post is created the title is added to document and when clicked on the title, click event works and shows an alert. when i create another post it's title also shows up with title of the first post but, none of them popup an alert when clicked.

```
 var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                "title": "",
                "postTxt":""
            }
        });

        <!-- Collection -->

        var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/UserPosts',
            model: PostModel
        });

        <!-- Views -->

        var PostModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new PostModel(),
            tagName: 'li',
            template: _.template($('#post-title').html()),
            initialize: function() {
                console.log('Initialized PostModelView........');
            },
            events: {
               'click a' : 'showAlert'
            },
            showAlert: function(){
                console.log('event');
                alert("You clicked : " + this.model.get('title'));
            },
            render: function() {
                console.log('Running render() of PostModelView.....');
                var htmloutput = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
                this.$el.html(htmloutput);
                return this;
            }
        });

        var postmodelview = new PostModelView();
        var postcollection = new PostCollection();

        var PostCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
            collection: postcollection,
            tagName: 'ul',
            initialize: function() {
                console.log('Initialized PostCollectionView .......');
                this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
                this.collection.on('remove', this.render, this);
                console.log('postcollectionview $el: ' + this.$el.html());
            },

            render: function() {


              this.collection.each(function(postmodel) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(postmodel));
                  var postmodelview = new PostModelView({model: postmodel});
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(postmodelview));
                  //var htmlout = postmodelview.render().$el;
                   var htmlout = this.$el.append(postmodelview.render().$el);
                  $('#postcontainer').html('');
                  $('#postcontainer').append(htmlout);
                  //this.$el.append(htmlout);

              },this);

              return this;

            }
        });



        function createPost() {

            var postcollectionview = new PostCollectionView();
            console.log('running creatPost()');
            var postmodel = new PostModel({ title: $('#title').val(), postTxt: $('#postTxt').val() });
            postcollection.create(postmodel);
            console.log("postcollection: " + JSON.stringify(postcollection.toJSON()));
             $('#title').val(''); //clears the input field
             $('#postTxt').val(''); // clears the input field

       }
```

Comment: Why not "collection" property instead of "model" in PostCollectionView? It's weird to read as it is now.

Comment: Also this line does nothing "var postmodelview = new PostModelView();".

And what are supposed to do last two lines of "createPost" functions? I don't understand your code.

Anyway I think the problem is in "$('#postcontainer').append(htmlout);". Maybe #postcontainer is not inside View's $el.

Comment: @MiguelSR changed  to "collection" property instead of "model" in PostCollectionView. the last two lines in createPost() clears  the input fields.

Comment: Ok @parthi.k, then you don't need the labels "title:" and "post:" :).

Comment: @Miguel: I had no intentions to put labels there, It was a typo, corrected it now.  As you said in your previous comment, the reason the event didn't fire is #postcontainer is not inside View's $el.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us have a closer look at this:

```
var htmlout = this.$el.append(postmodelview.render().$el);
$('#postcontainer').html('');
$('#postcontainer').append(htmlout);
```

`append`, like most jQuery functions, returns its receiver so `htmlout` is `this.$el`. That means that you are repeatedly clearing the content of `#postcontainer` and putting `this.$el` back into it.

What does `html('')` do? From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery **removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements** before replacing those elements with the new content.

Emphasis mine. So every time you:

```
$('#postcontainer').html('');
```

you're removing all the event handlers from `#postcontainer`'s children, in particular, you're removing all the events from `this.$el`.

You shouldn't be doing either of these things:

```
$('#postcontainer').html('');
$('#postcontainer').append(htmlout);
```

That view should just adding the subview's to its `el` and let the caller put its `el` on the page somewhere:

```
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(postmodel) {
        var postmodelview = new PostModelView({model: postmodel});
        this.$el.append(postmodelview.render().$el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

and then in the caller:

```
var postcollectionview = new PostCollectionView();
//...
#('#postcontainer').append(postcollectionview.render().el);
```

Various other issues:

1. Setting the `model` property on a view's prototype:

   ```
   var PostModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
       model: new PostModel(),
   ```

   doesn't make a lot of sense. Each instance of the view would normally have its own `model` and that should be supplied when the view is instantiated.
2. Similarly for setting the `collection` property on a view:

   ```
   var PostCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
       collection: postcollection,
   ```

   You'd normally set `collection` when you instantiate the view:

   ```
   var v = new PostCollectionView({ collection: post collection });
   ```
3. You have two different `postmodelview` variables in different scopes, the top level one is almost certainly a mistake.
4. You're using [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) at the bottom of `createPost` but labels don't make any sense in that context, I think you mean to say just this:

   ```
   $('#title').val('');   // clears the input field
   $('#postTxt').val(''); // clears the input field
   ```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tqdf2j0v/